# Multiple apps registration with Pushwoosh android in ionic

Tags: android, push-notification, pushwoosh

I am implementating pushnotification for one of my ionic apps. I have 2 applications registered with PushWoosh.Last month I had registered my device using the first pushwoosh app.It worked fine for many devices. Now I created another mobile application and tried implementing pushnotification and the registration always seems to fail. Is there a limitation that one device can register to only one pushwoosh notification? Cant I register my phone to multiple pushwoosh notifications?

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any problem with multiple apps (as long as they have different Apple Bundle Id).
What kind of message you receive when registration fails?

You should go through the very standard checks for iOS:

1. Is my profile push compatible?
   The app should display "allow push notifications" alert on start (at the very first launch only!).
2. Provisioning profile should have "aps-environment" string it in.
3. Do I use correct push notifications gateway? The gateway should match the provisioning profiles. Sandbox for development profiles and Production for AdHoc and AppStore builds.
4. Maybe my wi-fi router blocks APS ports? Wi-Fi will need to allow inbound and outbound TCP packets over port 5223.
5. Reboot the device. have you tried turning it off and on again.
6. What does the status of the push on "Pushes" page display?

(https://community.pushwoosh.com/questions/542/ios-no-notification-shown)

Comment: Based on the tags, this question is about Android, not iOS.

Comment: With Android it should be very easy as you can use one Google Project Number for various apps! The logs should be very helpful here and could give a lot of insights (such as INVALID_SENDER error or similar)